# how to rebuild screen to load data without having to refresh in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have Card Widget with Favorite button, Favorite Screen and Explore Screen. When I click CardWidget favorite button from Explore Screen, it supposed to show up in the Favorite Screen automatically but right now I have to refresh or hot reload to make the Card Widget to appear so if I can get any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

We are using BaseView with ChangeNotifierProvider( Consumer )

Card Widget Favorite Button

```
                                     child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              final fm = FavoriteModel(
                                                  id: widget.id,
                                                  name: widget.name,
                                                  ordinal: widget.ordinal,
                                                  showCards: false,
                                                  items: []);

                                              if (model.fav
                                                      .modelExists(fm.id) ==
                                                  -1) {
                                                model.fav.addToFavorite(
                                                    fm.id, fm, widget.item);
                                              }

                                              if (widget.item.favorited) {
                                                model.fav.removeFromFavorite(
                                                    fm.id, widget.item.id);
                                              } else {
                                                model.fav.addToFavorite(
                                                    fm.id, fm, widget.item);
                                              }
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Image(
                                            color:
                                                Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                            image: AssetImage(widget
                                                    .item.favorited
                                                ? 'assets/icons/more-icons/favorited-heart.png'
                                                : 'assets/icons/more-icons/unfavorited-heart.png'),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            height: 20,
                                          )),
```

I have uploaded my Favorite Screen right here so I would be really appreciated if anyone can take a look at it and help me solve it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/18d7KspFaqUTsAy-8QmrQ2MzmUEKb953GtS0J2mFSuIs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: have you tried using setState() in a stateful widget?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

Put the setState where you are calling the addToFavvorite :

```
if (model.fav.modelExists(fm.id) == -1) {
  setState(() {
    model.fav.addToFavorite(fm.id, fm, widget.item);
  });
}

if (widget.item.favorited) {
  setState(() {
    model.fav.removeFromFavorite(fm.id, widget.item.id);
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    model.fav.addToFavorite(fm.id, fm, widget.item);
  });
}
```

The function will rebuild the widget for you, use a StatefulWidget for it to work.

```
setState(() {
  //do stuff here
});
```

If you however need a StatelessWidget, consider using a StatefulBuilder.

Comment: can you pls take a look at my doc and can you tell me what to put inside the setState.

Comment: oh that onPress is not favorite button and that is my expanding button that expand all the stacked cards in my favorite Screen. That's also only appear after I refresh or hot reload too.

Comment: Hello.. I have tried but still it's not working; :(. by anychance do you have any other solution?

Comment: @AaseZi is there any different result now?

Comment: no not a different result... it's just not still appearing. by any chance we can connect via Zoom?. I can give you my discord, whataspp or other username.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned how are you dong routing. You can route to favorite page with navigator.

```
onTap() {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/favouritePage');
}
```

If you are trying to navigate using viewmodel/bloc then make sure you do not forget  to call `notifyListeners()`.

If you are sure there is no problem with viewmodel then there may be problem with you UI/Consumer widget.

Answer (score -1):

I think the flaw is in the context sent in the buildRow function. (try renaming it in itemBuilder)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
(...)
ListView.builder(
(..)
itemBuilder: (cxt, i) {
                     return Column(
                       children: [
                         buildRow(model.fav.favorites[i], cxt,
                             this.runtimeType),
                         SizedBox(
                           height: 20,
                         )
                       ],
                     );
                   },

}
```